# How to mask workflow_dispatch inputs, like secrets?

Tags: github, github-actions

```yaml
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      test_password:
        description: 'test_password'
        required: true

env:
  TEST_PASSWORD: ${{ github.event.inputs.test_password }}
```

The problem is that it prints `TEST_PASSWORD` input in the log. Is there a way to encrypt/mask this, similar to `${{ secrets.test_password }}`?

[This workaround](https://github.community/t/workflow-dispatch-is-it-possible-to-pass-a-secret-as-parameter/121819/6) no longer seems to work.

Comment: This is not currently possible, but there are workarounds. You might be interested in this thread: https://github.community/t/secure-github-action-inputs/122310/2

Answer (score 6):

This doesn't seem to be currently supported by [Github](https://github.community/t/workflow-dispatch-is-it-possible-to-pass-a-secret-as-parameter/121819) but you can retrieve the input and store it in a variable and then mask it, something like this:

```yaml
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      secret_value:
        type: string
        required: true
        description: Secret Value

jobs:
  secrets:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Masking inputs
        run: |
          SECRET_VALUE=$(cat $GITHUB_EVENT_PATH | jq -r '.inputs.secret_value' )
          echo "::add-mask::$SECRET_VALUE"
```