# How to mask user input for password field in github workflow_dispatch

Tags: github, github-actions, masking, github-secret, cleartext

Below is the github actions workflow:

```
name: CALLERDB - AD

on:

  workflow_dispatch:

    inputs:

      DBLoginID:
        description: 'Enter the user id'
        required: true
        type: string

      my_password:
        description: 'Enter your password'
        required: true
        type: password
```

I need the user to input the password which should not be clear text / visible.

Instead, it should be masked as dots `.` or asterisks `*`

But, as you can see in the snapshot below the password is very much visible in clear text.

[image]

I do not wish to save the password in github secrets as there are 150 users who will run the workflow with their individual id-passwords and the password policy sets the password to expire every 2 months.

Can you please suggest what would be a a feasible solution here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GitHub Actions: How to mask workflow\_dispatch inputs, like secrets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67608874/github-actions-how-to-mask-workflow-dispatch-inputs-like-secrets)

Comment: This is not possible. There is no way to mask input as secret and display it as starts on UI.

Comment: ah you need a `password` input type? did you already see this?  https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/12764